# (Re)scheduleTimerWithInterval possible?

Tags: ios

I'm using scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval: to perform an animation every N seconds.

In some circumstances I want to reschedule thing so the N starts recounting again i.e.

schduleTimerWithTimeInterval: 5

after 5 seconds perform action

after 5 seconds perform action

2 seconds elapse since the last action then something X happens

5 seconds since X, perform action (i.e. not 5 seconds since the last perform action)

after 5 seconds perform action

after 5 seconds perform action

So when X occurs, is it possible to reset the scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(takeAShot) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and then when x occurs:

```
[self.timer invalidate];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(takeAShot) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Or any number of ways with repeating and non repeating timers